# Jasmine test run with Karma cannot find Angular method called from onload

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

First off I am new to Karma, I have the following code in an application...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    angular.element('#eventListController').scope().initEvents();
});
```

but when I run karma I see....

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initEvents' of undefined
```

What am I missing here? I am using a Sanity check test...

```
describe("Sanity test for jasmine", function() {
    it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

**Update**

So I think I am having this issue because there is no DOM right now. How do I mock out this DOM I guess would be the real question.

new version still failing...

```
describe("Sanity test for jasmine", function() {
    beforeEach(module("Events"));
    describe("TailsCtrl", function () {
        var scope,
            controller;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller;
        }));

        it("should assign message to hello world", function () {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

**Update**

Looks like I need jasmine-jquery but it fails to install on my local windows GRRRRRR

Answer (score 1):

What are you testing? A controller? A directive? You have to provide a real scope for your tests. Here is an example for a controller test in jasmine:

```
  describe("controller", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      HomeCtrl = $controller('HomeCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $rootScope: $rootScope });
      $rootScope.$digest();
    });

    it("foobar", function() {});
  });
```

Now your controller has a real scope, mocked out for your tests.

Comment: I am testing a controller. I have included the test I came up with that still fails but is similar to what you are saying. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need a couple plugins and something like this will work

http://a-developer-life.blogspot.com/2011/06/jasmine-part-2-spies-and-mocks.html